# Extract multiple values from raster using for loop

Tags: r, raster

I'm trying to extract multiple cell values from a raster using the following for-loop:

```
testis <- NULL
for(i in paste0("y", 2011:2019)){
  testis[i] <- raster::extract(rf[[c(1, 3)]], i[, 1:2])
}
```

In replacement for:

```
e_change <- raster::extract(rf[[c(1, 3)]], y2019[, 1:2]) #extract cell values
```

Although, I get the following error:

> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
> error in evaluating the argument 'y' in selecting a method for function 'extract': incorrect number of dimensions

Answer (score 0):

In general use example data (see ?stack).

the error occurs because you iterate over a character vector (`paste0("y",2011:2019`) that is one-dimensional and you try to subset it like data.frame `i[,1:2]` which is two-dimensional.
However, the second element of `raster::extract()` should be:

> points represented by a two-column matrix or data.frame, or SpatialPoints*; SpatialPolygons*; SpatialLines; sf spatial vector objects; Extent; or a numeric vector representing cell numbers

so you can't extract anything from a character vector.
you can extract value with cells number or points location, which would seem what you want to do

```
r <- raster(ncol=36, nrow=18, vals=1:(18*36))
s <- stack(r,r*2,r/3)
#extract with cell number
raster::extract(s[[c(1, 3)]],c(1:100),df=T)
#extract with points
xy <- cbind(-50, seq(-80, 80, by=20))
raster::extract(s[[c(1, 3)]],xy,df=T)
sp <- SpatialPoints(xy)
raster::extract(s[[c(1, 3)]],sp,df=T)
```

Just a note for the speed issue. If values extraction is computationally intense due to the stack dimension or the number of points (or polygon), there is a wonderful function `exact_extract()` from `exactextractr` [package](https://github.com/isciences/exactextractr)  that is waaaaay faster than `raster::extract()` and have more or less the same argument.

Comment: I think my aim was to extract values from the raster containing years from 2010-2019, in one loop as with 'extract(x, y)', I would have to change 'y' for each year.

Comment: But what is 'y'? is it a polygon object? is it a vector of cell index? is it a point object? And what information is contained in your raster? the year between 2010 and 2019? from your code, it seems that your raster is a raster stack (you subset it like a stack, `rf[[c(1,3]]`. Please make a reproducible example

Comment: I'm not so sure as it's been some time since I have used this dataset. Although, if I would have a guess, then `rf` is a raster containing estimated probabilities of encountering a bird, with a probability from 0 to 1, across a region relative to various habitats. `y2019`, I had yearly habitat data since 2010, and I believe that this extracts those values in the cell belonging to the habitats, and regions. Because `rf` was derived from data included in `y2010 to y2019` using random forests. I presume I converted `y2019` from raster to point data, so that I can extract via coordinates.

Comment: The aim was like I mentioned before, a loop to extract across multiple rasters and store the results into testis.

Comment: in all the `extract` function (i.e. `raster::extract`, `terra::extract` and `exactextractr::exact_extract`) you can extract values from a raster stack ( a multi-layer raster) without the need of looping across the layer. For this reason, I still don't understand what you really want to do. If you have a point object (i.e. of class `SpatialPoints`, `SpatialPointsDataFrame`,`sf`, `spatVect` ecc) you can simply do: `raster::extract(rasterstack,pointobj)`

Comment: please spend some time creating a reproducible example, and give us the taste of the output your looking for

Comment: Aha! That makes good sense. I perhaps should have stacked the datasets for yearly habitats,then performed ```raster::extract```.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231216/discussion-between-elia-and-lime).